# Does VTDecompressionSession support smoothing frames via presentationTimestamp (to fix stuttering)

Tags: ios, video, video-streaming, decoding, video-toolbox

I noticed the API for VT decompression (VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrameWithOutputHandler) takes a presentationTimestamp, and there is also an argument kVTDecodeFrame_EnableTemporalProcessing that is used to reorder frames.

I am having a problem with stuttering due to network variability and wondering if this API also has buffering built in so that frames can be evened out using the PTS to reduce stutter. Or does separately buffering logic need to be written custom?